# Why do I get error: 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<String>' conform to 'StringProtocol' when trying to iterate through a binding object?

Tags: loops, swiftui, binding, state

I am trying to iterate through an array called: `contacts` that is an array of `Contact` (a hashable struct with contact data). This works when I iterate through the array directly (as in, placing the array directly into the Foreach block without using any type of binding) however, when I try to pass in the array via a binding, using the key: `$contacts`, I get the error: `Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<String>' conform to 'StringProtocol'`

I feel like the concept is similar but I am still wrapping my head around how swift works. Please see the below code:

**Here is where I set up the binding (where the error appears)**

```
struct ContactsGridView: View {

@Binding var contacts: [Contact]

let threeColumnGrid = [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20),
                       GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20),
                       GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20)]

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            // Contacts Scroll View
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach($contacts, id: \.self) { contact in
                        VStack {
                            Circle()
                                .fill(.white)
                            Text(contact.firstName) // Here is where I get the error.
                        }
                    }
                }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20,
                                     leading: 20,
                                     bottom: 20,
                                     trailing: 20))
            }
        }.background(Color(CustomColors.background.rawValue))
    }
}
```

}

**And here is where I set up the State:**

```
struct ContactsViewController: View {

@State private var selectedTab: Int = 0
@State private var employeeContacts: [Contact] = employeeContactsTempData
@State private var clientContacts: [Contact] = clientContactsTempData

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        Divider()
            .background(.thinMaterial)
            .navigationTitle("Contacts")
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: $selectedTab) {
                Text("Employees").tag(0)
                Text("Clients").tag(1)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
            
            switch(selectedTab) {
            case 0: ContactsGridView(contacts: $employeeContacts)
            case 1: ContactsGridView(contacts: $clientContacts)
            default:
                ContactsGridView(contacts: $employeeContacts)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It should be `{ $contact in` when using the binding syntax.

Comment: That worked. Interesting, I would've thought only first reference to the binding property would've needed that.